# Multiple MultiSelect Drowdowns Per Form - how to get all the values generically

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropdown

Getting values of multiple dropdown bootstrap select in one form - loaded generically via php.

It is simple to get all the values of 1 multiselect dropdown that is hard coded.
I am loading multiple selects for a survey questionnaire that is generic

```
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple  name="Question[' . $x . '][' .$row['RecordId'] . ']">
        <option value="1">Card 1</option>
        <option value="2">Card 2</option>
        <option value="3">Card 3</option>
    </select>

    //options are loaded - above is just for example
       <option value="">None</option>';
                    foreach ($arrOptions as $rowOptions) {
                        $strReturnHtml .= '
                            <option value="' . $rowOptions . '">' . 
       $rowOptions . '</option>';
                    }
                    $strReturnHtml .= '
                        </select>';
                    break;
```

There will be multiple of these dropdowns per form.

Comment: Hello there, you need to clean your code and give an example of what you want as this is not clear at all.
I think you might be able to solve your issue alone. Simply use the developper console (F12) and check the resulting html

Comment: Use the same loop logic that creates your dropdowns to process the submitted data

Comment: Problem here is multiple dropdowns get created via a foreach loop. Therefore all the name, and Id's are generic. How do I link that up to js. If the code was static it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple  name="que_list[]">
            <?php foreach ($arrOptions as $rowOptions) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rowOptions['id']?>"><?php echo $rowOptions['name']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

    NOTE : On server side you can get select value using this...
     print_r($_POST['que_list']);
    Array ( [0] => card-1 [1] => card-2)
```